# VBA Find last row in very large Spreadsheet (Overflow Error)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have the raw Output of a data conversion sheet (with PDF2XL). The sheet has 240k rows. The script itself runs nicely, but only if I declare the variable "LastRowI" up to 30k. For higher values I get a "Error 6 Overflow"

I use the standard way of getting the last row.

```
LastrowC = Worksheets("control").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

So my question is how to get the last line of a big Excel sheet without producing an Overflow error?

Comment: Why can't you get the last row by iterating each row yourself? Try Worksheets("control").Rows.Count

Comment: instead of `.end()` try to use `Worksheets("control").UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: @Dave the sheet has empty a few empty rows, this would make a Loop checking for non empty rows messy (at least from my limited understanding of VBA.

Comment: @MarioAdenauer, then start from the bottom up :)  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro

Comment: thanks for the help guys. Your method works, but I prefer the solution from eirikdaude below. Way simpler to just declare the variable as Long

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that in VBA the `Int` type is a signed 16-bit field, so it can only hold values from -32,768 to +32,767. Change your `LastRow` variable to `Long`, which is a signed 32-bit field and can hold values from -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647.

Intuitively you'd think that using an `int` instead of a `long` may be more effective as the former is smaller than the latter, but as you can see [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/4497791), VBA converts `int`s to `long`s anyway, so you might as well use `long` all the time when you deal with integers (whole numbers).

Comment: thank you, the Overflow error dissapears now when I define LastrowI. But now I get an Overflow error pointing to the first for Loop ( For k = 1 to LastrowI). The Problem moved only down by one line.

Comment: Of course I have to declare the Loop variable as Long as well, my bad. thank your very much